# Trying to add UIImagePicker Moving to different ViewController and view is not in heirachy

Tags: ios, swift

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to present a UIImagePicker to select an image from the phone's photo library

### What is the issue

When I run the code I get this error message:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x160062000> on 
<Nebula.SettingsViewController: 0x15f51b3c0> (from <Nebula.SettingsViewController: 
0x15f51b3c0>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
```

It also navigates to the first View Controller of my app (even if this hasn't been shown before to the user in this session)

### What have I tried to do to fix it

I used [this post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114337) to try and use the topVC and present from there, this stops the error however still returns me to a different View Controller therefore doesn't allow me to run anymore code from the proper view controller

### My code

```
@IBAction func pickTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        //let topVC = topMostController()
        //topVC.present(picker, animated: true)
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("No image selected")
        return
    }
    guard let imageData = image.pngData() else {
        print("Something wrong with image data")
        return
    }
}
```

top most VC code

```
func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
    var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
    while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController!
    }
    return topController
}
```

Comment: Is the code you're showing inside `SettingsViewController`?  If you use the commented code to get `topVC` what kind of object does that return?

Comment: It is supposed to return a View Controller however it is now returning nil and yes it is in SettingsViewController

Comment: cause the error is looking like a plist file, I added a detailed answer below.